# An excerpt/wiki improve suggestion to [tag:LaTeX]

Tags: discussion, tags

When a user wants to ask a question about [latex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) then he probably goes to tag his question by [latex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex). In the excerpt of such tag we read:

> LaTeX is a document markup language and document preparation system for the TeX typesetting program. Note that http://tex.stackexchange.com is specifically dedicated to LaTeX (and TeX) questions.

Even in the tag wiki there is no exact guide to the user which are the on-topic questions about TeX for *Academia*.

This tag excerpt/wiki may have to be improved in the following areas;

1. The user is very probable to be mis-understood into which website should s/he ask the question. As in the excerpt does not distinguish the exact questions which are on-topic for Academia. I think that the excerpt should include the following points:

   - The user may ask about the use of LaTeX in his academic publications; such as the use of LaTeX in preparing manuscripts for the journals.
   - *Technical* issues should go directly to the LaTeX.SE and are off-topic Academia.
2. When the link to http://tex.stackexchange.com is mentioned, the link may be better to be replaced by [TeX/StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) or something similar to avoid using direct links.

Also there are some questions about other typesetting softwares like [Microsoft Word](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=microsoft%2Bword+closed%3A0) and [Libre Office](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=libreoffice+closed%3A0) which there is no tag for them.

So, the question here is whether there is any need to improve the [latex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag and if you are positive with this edit, what should be the improved tag excerpt/wiki look like?

Or, Is it a better idea to create a new [typesetting](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) tag and merge the existing [latex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) into it to avoid misunderstandings of the existing tag and also cover other typesetting questions.

Comment: In general, I think that the current description is fine (maybe "Technical questions should be asked on [site]" instead of the current form). Ad. 2. Why?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal what about the typesetting tag?

Comment: I am not sure. Could you provide example questions that would benefit from this tag? If it is less than 5, we can use our time more efficiently than discussing it.